# Ajax HTTP Post ClientDoneRequest longer in IE than Chrome

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is a simple ajax http post request made through Javascript to MVC web api. It responds much faster in chrome than in IE. Fiddler shows delay between ClientBeginRequest and ClientDoneRequest is a big gap in IE. What could be reason for below situation? Is there any Javascript code suggestion

**Fiddler statistics IE browser**

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      1,800      (headers:1,697; body:103)
Bytes Received:  445        (headers:276; body:169)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE

This traffic was captured on Wednesday, January 04, 2017.

ClientConnected:    08:28:38.989
ClientBeginRequest: 08:28:47.530
GotRequestHeaders:  08:28:47.530
ClientDoneRequest:  08:28:47.787
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    08:28:38.532
FiddlerBeginRequest:    08:28:47.787
ServerGotRequest:   08:28:47.788
ServerBeginResponse:    08:28:47.798
GotResponseHeaders: 08:28:47.798
ServerDoneResponse: 08:28:47.798
ClientBeginResponse:    08:28:47.798
ClientDoneResponse: 08:28:47.798

Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.268

RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)

   ~headers~: 276
application/json: 169
```

**Fiddler statistics Chrome browser**

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      1,872      (headers:1,769; body:103)
Bytes Received:  547        (headers:378; body:169)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE


This traffic was captured on Wednesday, January 04, 2017.

ClientConnected:    08:45:05.547
ClientBeginRequest: 08:45:13.387
GotRequestHeaders:  08:45:13.388
ClientDoneRequest:  08:45:13.388
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    08:45:06.249
FiddlerBeginRequest:    08:45:13.388
ServerGotRequest:   08:45:13.388
ServerBeginResponse:    08:45:13.398
GotResponseHeaders: 08:45:13.398
ServerDoneResponse: 08:45:13.398
ClientBeginResponse:    08:45:13.398
ClientDoneResponse: 08:45:13.398

Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.011

RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)

   ~headers~: 378
application/json: 169
```

Comment: `Is there any Javascript code suggestion` - yes, post some

Comment: is there any browser specific javascript code that can solve this performance issue?

Comment: without seeing the code that produces these results, who can say